# Oracle Import Issue

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g, oracle-apex

Could someone please help me with this oracle import error?

I have paste the session transcript in http://dpaste.com/807025/

If you look at my first attempt, there is no error as such but nothing get imported.

If you look at my first attempt, I had to specify the name of the table and then i get the error.

Question :

1. Is it mandatory to specify the tables to import? Shouldn't the export utility just import all the tables that are present in the dump file?
2. How can i solve the error in import? I have 6.75 GB Disk space free but still get this error.

Please guide.

Comment: One quick google for the error number would have took you straight to an answer. http://ora-01659.ora-code.com/

Comment: I don't see any error. All I see is a warning and that's it. The second import was still successful as it says `Import terminated successfully with warnings`! However, it may be a good idea to allocate some more space by `ADD DATAFILE`....

Comment: I did a lot of googling around and when I could not find a solution, I posted it here. To solve this problem, I added a extra data file to my tablespace and import worked fine. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should try is importing using the SYSTEM user rather than your LOCALDB user. This will allow `imp` to create users and schema objects as required. However, this may not actually eliminate your errors, it could simply cause different errors to appear.

Your import file contains ALL of the internal oracle specification data for every object, including tablespace specifications. If your XE database isn't configured in the same way as the database you're exporting from, you're going to encounter some other setup issues.

Given the number of unknowns, you might be best served by trying to do something small and simple before trying to achieve your full goals. For example, log in to your XE database as `SYSTEM`, create the `WMOS` user and grant them the basics, and then use `IMP` to import a single small table. Once you get a simple base case working, you should be able to scale up to your full import.

One additional observation: you're using the old-school `IMP` tool rather than `IMPDP`, which imposes some constraints on you. If you have access to the main database and can run your export with `EXPDP`, you *might* find things better.

For what it's worth, [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is full of DBAs and much deeper knowledge for these types of issues than is normally covered here on SO.

Comment: I added a extra data file to my tablespace and import works fine. Thanks all for your feedback. It helped me through to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the database name used in the script it looks like your using Oracle XE which has size limits on how much storage it will create and use for user data. The limits are 4GB of user data for Oracle XE 10g and 11GB for Oracle XE 11g. That means the create statement that shows in the error is likely going over the limits as it starts the table off with approx 3.4GB of storage.

```
STORAGE(INITIAL 3409969152
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I finally added a extra data file to my tablespace and import works fine. Thanks all for your feedback. It helped me through to a solution.